# Unable to create new remote session. Appium

Tags: java, android, macos, selenium, appium

```
public class StartFirstJobTest {

AppiumDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "F4AZFG07P508");
    //capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    //capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```

**When I try to run the test, I get this error.**

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
>   [{platformName=Android, deviceName=F4AZFG07P508}], required
>   capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version: '3.3.1',
>   revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000' System info:
>   host: 'MacBook-Pro-Roman.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:77:aef0:77:32%en0',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

I think that I set everything up correctly in the appium (When the inspector starts, the device is installed applications and can be tested)

As a project collector I use Maven

UPD.
**I'm trying to automate the application. I specified additional capabilities in the code**

```
    @BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File app = new File("/Users/romanderabin/Downloads/TimeTracker.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","F4AZFG07P508");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid.MainActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub/"), capabilities);
```

**and the error is the same**

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
>   [{app=/Users/romanderabin/Downloads/TimeTracker.apk,
>   appPackage=com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid,
>   appActivity=com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid.MainActivity,
>   platformVersion=5.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=F4AZFG07P508}],
>   required capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version:
>   '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
>   System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-Roman.local', ip:
>   'fe80:0:0:0:77:aef0:77:32%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver
>   info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:92)
>     at StartFirstJobTest.setUp(StartFirstJobTest.java:30)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:648)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:616)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>
> Test ignored.

**Appium logs when I'm trying start test**

> [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/romanderabin/Downloads/TimeTracker.apk","appPackage":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid","appActivity":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid.MainActivity","platformVersion":"5.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"F4AZFG07P508"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/romanderabin/Downloads/TimeTracker.apk","appPackage":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid","appActivity":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid.MainActivity","platformVersion":"5.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"F4AZFG07P508"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"alwaysMatch":{"app":"/Users/romanderabin/Downloads/TimeTracker.apk","appPackage":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid","appActivity":"com.ronasit.timetrackerandroid.MainActivity","platformVersion":"5.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"F4AZFG07P508"},"firstMatch":[]}
>
> [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were
>   incorrect. We wanted
>   {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]}
>   and you sent
>   ["desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities","capabilities","alwaysMatch","firstMatch"]
>
> [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 4 ms - 228

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. Update the Appium Java-client version 4.1.2 to 5.0.0 BETA6 and use the Selenium-Java version 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

When handling version compatibility, Maven repository provides Compile Dependencies option. Simply scroll down on Maven Repository website and you will see this section.

Comment: Add link for the page you are referring  and explain more clearly on how it will solve the problem.

Comment: I you navigate to this url: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/8.2.0  One can observe "Compile Dependencies" section on the webpage.                   
                                                                                                                             
Compile Dependencies (2)
Category/License  Group / Artifact Version Updates

Apache 2.0 logo org.seleniumhq.selenium » selenium-api [4.4.0, 5.0) 4.6.0

Apache 2.0 logo org.seleniumhq.selenium » selenium-remote-driver [4.4.0, 5.0) 4.6.0

Answer (score 1):

In your IDE, go and run the below command in the terminal

appium --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload

This will install the chromedrivers and you are all set to run the code on chrome browsers

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using an Physical Device and not an emulator. In both cases we need to mention either the browser or app file details in the desired capabilities. I assume that you haven't mentioned those things in code as well as in Appium GUI. Below is the sample code for testing for testing an hybrid apk using appium.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ANDROID");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName",Constant.appPlatform);
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", Constant.appPackage);
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",Constant.appActivity);
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

This code will invoke the application opened in the target device with the mentioned app activity in the desired capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a real device. Unfortunately, your decision did not help me. Can I have a problem with compatibility versions between appium and selenium?

Comment: The issue here is with the desired capabilities. I could help you better if I know what you are trying to achieve exactly. Are you automating browser or app in the mobile. If you are going to automate app, above code should work. Incase of browser automation we need to change the desired capabilities. The error code clearly shows you have passed only two desired capabilities. Android and device name. None of the browser or app capabilities are passed.

Comment: Capabilities are good it seems. Can you update the full err code. Appium also tells the reason for not creating a session

Comment: I checked the err code but i doesn't got any clue. While using eclipse we used to get the reason also along with err like 
    "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Command duration or timeout: 29.76 seconds"     as mentioned as original error. Have you checked the appium log. Also  make sure the port number while initiating the driver. The example code i have used "4727". It should be same as the appium port.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, friend. I found a solution to the problem and hope it will help others

Comment: Good.. make sure your updated version support s all your existing code. For eg find by name is not supported in higher versions

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the device. I changed the device and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, beccause I used appPackage from manifest. Should get appPackage from gradle (applicationId).

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue, since as I understood you are running Appium on the same machine where your client scripts reside, try using "http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub". this solution works for me.

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```