# unable to create remote session-appium

Tags: automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to connect appium inspector with desktop calculator through the following desired Capabilities

```
{
  "platformName": "Windows",
  "platformVersion": "10",
  "deviceName": "WindowsPC",
  "app": "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
}
```

but I get an error:

Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4724

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create new remote session. Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409349/unable-to-create-new-remote-session-appium)

Answer (score 0):

The default connect port is 4723, if you use 4724, you are using the custom server configuration. Make sure that appium server is running on port 4724.

Also make sure that developer mode enabled
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

and you've started appium server, and appium desktop app as Administrator.